# Sorting array of multiple dictionaries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

My array contains three dictionaries per object of the array.

```
{
    avg = {
        avg1 = 50;
        avg2 = 60;
    };

    posts =         {
        alcoholContent = 450;
        name = "BBB";
        origin = United States;

    };

    reviews =  {

        rev1 = "Test review 1";
        rev2 = "Test review 2";
    };
}

{
    avg = {
        avg1 = 30;
        avg2 = 20;
    };

    posts =         {
        alcoholContent = 550;
        name = "AAA";
        origin = United States;

    };

    reviews =  {

        rev1 = "Test review 1";
        rev2 = "Test review 2";
    };
}
```

I want to sort array acceding by key **"name"** (of post dictionary).
How can I do it?

I tried normal sorting methods using sort descriptors, but did not work

Comment: Sort descriptors should work. Could you post an example of what you did?

Comment: Thanks for answer. This is what I did     NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
        sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name"
                                                      ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
        NSArray *sortedArray;
        sortedArray = [arrItems sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sortUsingComparator:

```
[array sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSDictionary *dict1 = obj1;
    NSDictionary *dict2 = obj2;

    NSString *string1 = [[dict1 objectForKey:@"posts"] objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *string2 = [[dict2 objectForKey:@"posts"] objectForKey:@"name"];

    return [string1 compare:string2];
}];
```