# How to sort date?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i have array Like :

```
<__NSArrayM 0x79f3a4a0>(
{
    "act_date" = "02/03/2015";
    "act_id" = 3;
    "act_name" = test2;
},
{
    "act_date" = "03/03/2015";
    "act_id" = 4;
    "act_name" = test3;
},
{
    "act_date" = "01/03/2015";
    "act_id" = 5;
    "act_name" = test1;
}
)
```

i want to sort array with date. 
i tried this method :

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString *dateString in tblList)
{
    NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:[dateString valueForKey:@"act_date"]];
    [tempArray addObject:date];
}

   [tempArray sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDate *date1, NSDate *date2) {
        // return date2 compare date1 for descending. Or reverse the call for ascending.
        return [date2 compare:date1];
    }];
```

But it returns only array with date, how do I add my all data with sorted date array??

Comment: Your problem is not the dates, it's that you have an array of dictionaries. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193077/sorting-array-of-multiple-dictionaries

Comment: Your result returns only array with date because you add only "act_date" value to tempArray try add your object to tempArray . In sortUsingComparator: return [yourObject2.act_date compare yourObject1.act_date]

Comment: Instead of working with dictionaries, convert them to objects. Obj-C is not javascript so you shouldn't be working with objects converted to dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this, if you need to convert the values of `"act_date"` to an proper `NSDate` before comparison:

```
NSDateFormatter *_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

NSArray *_yourOriginalArray = // ...
NSArray *_sortedArray = [_yourOriginalArray sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary * obj1, NSDictionary * obj2) {
    return [[_dateFormatter dateFromString:[obj2 valueForKey:@"act_date"]] compare:[_dateFormatter dateFromString:[obj1 valueForKey:@"act_date"]]];
}];
```

then the `_sortedArray` will have the items sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You are taking out Date from your array, it is not need, you can still sort array of dictionary by using method like below.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"act_date" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [tblList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple NSSortDescriptor

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"act_date" ascending:YES selector:@selector(compare:)];
array = [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];
```

If you want you can add more descriptor to sort for instance by act_id. The priority is set by the oreder of sort descriptors in the array that you pass to the method `-sortUsingDescriptor`
**[EDIT]**
As pointed out by holex act_date is a string and it should be converted to `NSdate` by using `NSDateFormatter`. Or you will just sort strings.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorting an array of dictionaries with date-

```
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"act_date" ascending:NO];
[mArrTimeline sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: NSDate is not a valid key for the structure shown by the OP

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. May be useful to you.

```
NSString *strKey = @"act_date";
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:strKey ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName];
tempArr = (NSMutableArray *)[arr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```